# Custom Swift Library in NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript

I want create a custom plugin for Nativescript this plugin contains a custom shared universal framework written in Swift.

When i add my test framework to a test xcode project then it works fine.
But when i add this framework to my nativescript test app and i call the library i get this error:

```
File:///app/tns_modules/hello/index.js:8:15: ReferenceError: Metadata for "hello.Hello" found but symbol not available at runtime.
```

I don't know what is the problem, pleas help me to understand this.

Here my repos for the test products:

[iOS Framework Github Repo](https://github.com/nor-bu/ios-framework-hello-world.git)

[Test App Github Repo](https://github.com/nor-bu/ns-hello-world-custom-plugin-library.git)

Comment: check the link blow where a similiar issue to yours was logged https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/543

Comment: Detailed answet for this issue logged in the runtime repository can be fiound here https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/581#issuecomment-226411959